# Rest Assured useRelaxedHTTPSValidation and Java 6 issues

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, rest-assured

I have a REST API test suite that uses Rest Assured 2.4.0. Login to the application is using a POST call. I am working around the cert validation by using RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation() 
statically for all requests. The tests run just fine with JDK 1.7.0_79 but are failing with SocketException errors when running with JDK 1.6.0_43. (on Windows 7)

Here is how I login and get Authorization Header which are needed for all requests

```
public static RequestSpecification userWithAuthHeader() throws IOException {
    testData = readTestDataFile();
    RestAssured.baseURI = testData.getString("environment.URI");
    RestAssured.basePath = testData.getString("environment.Path");
    RestAssured.config.getHttpClientConfig().reuseHttpClientInstance();
    RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
    String user =  testData.getString("user.username");
    String password = testData.getString("user.password");
    String domain = testData.getString("user.domain");
    String acceptHeader = testData.getString("acceptHeader");
    String auth= post("/system/login?domain=" + domain + "&user=" + user + "&pw=" + password).getHeader("Authorization");
    RequestSpecification requestSpec = with().log().all().headers("Authorization", auth, "Accept", acceptHeader);
    return requestSpec;
```

}

The post method above fails when running it on Windows 7 with JDK 6  with the following errors:

```
Running com.org.group.preCheckInSPTests.getAppliancesTest
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
May 24, 2015 7:54:26 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {s}->https://<IP_ADDRESS>:
Connection reset
May 24, 2015 7:54:26 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect to {s}->https://<IP_ADDRESS>
May 24, 2015 7:54:26 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {s}->https://<IP_ADDRESS>:
Connection reset
May 24, 2015 7:54:26 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect to {s}->https://<IP_ADDRESS>
May 24, 2015 7:54:26 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {s}->https://<IP_ADDRESS>:
Connection reset
May 24, 2015 7:54:26 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect to {s}->https://<IP_ADDRESS>
Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 6.116 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.org.group.preCheckInSPTests.getAppliancesTest
loginAsUser(com.org.group.preCheckIn.getAppliancesTest)  Time elapsed: 5.846 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:460)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1764)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.post(HTTPBuilder.java:333)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$post$2.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1067)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.this$2$sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:31)
        at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:49)
        at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeFilterChain(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:956)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1414)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.this$2$applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149) 
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:154) 
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) 
        at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.post(RestAssured.java:832)
```

Any ideas on what is causing the issue ? And how I can resolve the issue ?

Comment: The solution here is the POODLE vulnerability issue that was fixed earlier this year. Clients using Java 6 need to set -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1" when making  a HTTPS request.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is the POODLE vulnerability issue that was fixed earlier this year. Clients using Java 6 need to set -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1" when making a HTTPS request. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html